# Nodejs cluster not listing

Tags: node.js

This is copied from nodejs api:

What I want to do is to do background job in master, and accept http request in worker.

If I comment out the background job part, it works well.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const sleep = require('sleep');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });


  // background jobs start
  while(true) {
    console.log(123)
    sleep.sleep(1) // do_background_jobs()
  }
  // background jobs end


} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Here is logs:

```
Master 45476 is running
Worker 45479 started
Worker 45483 started
Worker 45482 started
Worker 45478 started
```

But `netstat` shows 8000 is closed. of cource `curl` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is blocking the "[event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)" therefore nothing can happen in the main process. you should convert your while loop to this code to prevent blocking IO.

```
setInterval(() => {
   console.log("123")
}, 1000)
```

Comment: But as you can see `Worker 45482 started`, master is blocked by while, why separate worker process is also blocked?

Comment: The code that print to the screen Is in the main process (console.log..) but you cannot see the output if the main process Is busy.

Comment: I can see `123` output. But since  `Worker 45482 started` is printed, so `http.createServer` in worker process is also executed. but `8000` port is not open.